# How to create this barrel / radial distortion with Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I'm making a custom virtual reality headset with code in python / opencv. I need to be able to distort the images to create the "barrel distortion" / "radial distortion" effect.

Some images to explain:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I already have the `source_image` that I want to use and show to the user, and already have them side-by-side. Now I just need something like `out = cv2.createBarrelDistortion(source_image, params)`. (and I wouldn't mind being able to tune a few params like center of distortion, magnitude of distortion, etc, so I can make it look right for whatever custom lenses I get.)

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: If you are willing to use Python Wand, which uses ImageMagick, then see ImageMagick -distort barrel and find the equivalent distorting in Python Wand. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#barrel and http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.9/wand/image.html (search for distort)

Comment: thanks I'll check it out! I'm open to using anything Python that can eventually give me a numpy array to show in cv2. Feel free to add an answer with a simple test showing it :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how to do that in Python Wand 0.5.9

(http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.9/index.html)

Input:

[image]

```
from wand.image import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2


with Image(filename='checks.png') as img:
    print(img.size)
    img.virtual_pixel = 'transparent'
    img.distort('barrel', (0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
    img.save(filename='checks_barrel.png')
    # convert to opencv/numpy array format
    img_opencv = np.array(img)

# display result with opencv
cv2.imshow("BARREL", img_opencv)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#barrel for the same example and discussion of arguments.

See https://hackaday.io/project/12384-autofan-automated-control-of-air-flow/log/41862-correcting-for-lens-distortions for Python/OpenCV approach.

Comment: your code uses OpenCV to show image on the screen. and the question is, how to create the distortion with OpenCV.

Comment: `@lenik` The OP said above that Python Wand would be acceptable and that he just needed to get the result as a bumpy array that could be used in OpenCV. So I do not know why you downgraded my answer. I only posted that after he said it would be acceptable

Comment: Hey I should have clarified. I'm open to using any python library to accomplish this task, though my final 'show image' function will be with opencv. This answer is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 6):

I would be using scipy , but only for interpolation:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import scipy.ndimage
```

....

```py
#img: input image

# adjust k_1 and k_2 to achieve the required distortion
k_1 = 0.2
k_2 = 0.05

#img = imread("...")

h,w = [99,100] # img size

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.float32(np.arange(w)),np.float32(np.arange(h))) # meshgrid for interpolation mapping


# center and scale the grid for radius calculation (distance from center of image)
x_c = w/2 
y_c = h/2 
x = x - x_c
y = y - y_c
x = x/x_c
y = y/y_c

radius = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) # distance from the center of image

m_r = 1 + k_1*radius + k_2*radius**2 # radial distortion model

# apply the model 
x= x * m_r 
y = y * m_r

# reset all the shifting
x= x*x_c + x_c
y = y*y_c + y_c

distorted = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(img, [y.ravel(),x.ravel()])
distorted.resize(img.shape)
```

....

We are using a simple model, the `m_r` factor multiplied to each `x,y` gives a stretch as it moves the points further away.
Finally we interpolate the distorted points and get our image.

[image: Original Image]

[image: Distorted Image]

Comment: Since the equation for the radial distortion is $$1 + k_1 r^2 + k_2 r^4 + k_3 r^6
$$, `radius` should not be squared. Besides, when `k_1` is 0.2 and `k_2` is 0.05 while others remain 0, $$1 + k_1 r^2 + k_2 r^4 + k_3 r^6
$$ is monotonically increasing, should this produces a pincushion distortion according to [OpenCV doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.13/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#:%7E:text=The%20next%20figures,monotonically%20increasing:~:text=The%20next%20figures,monotonically%20increasing)?

Answer (score 0):

We can replace `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates()` with `PIL`'s `ImageOps.deform()` in Sankalp Bhamare's Barrel implementation to obtain the same desired distortion:

```
from PIL import ImageOps

class BarrelDeformer:

    def transform(self, x, y):
        # center and scale the grid for radius calculation (distance from center of image)
        x_c, y_c = w / 2, h / 2 
        x = (x - x_c) / x_c
        y = (y - y_c) / y_c
        radius = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) # distance from the center of image
        m_r = 1 + k_1*radius + k_2*radius**2 # radial distortion model
        # apply the model 
        x, y = x * m_r, y * m_r
        # reset all the shifting
        x, y = x*x_c + x_c, y*y_c + y_c
        return x, y

    def transform_rectangle(self, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        return (*self.transform(x0, y0),
                *self.transform(x0, y1),
                *self.transform(x1, y1),
                *self.transform(x1, y0),
                )

    def getmesh(self, img):
        self.w, self.h = img.size
        gridspace = 20
        target_grid = []
        for x in range(0, self.w, gridspace):
            for y in range(0, self.h, gridspace):
                target_grid.append((x, y, x + gridspace, y + gridspace))
        source_grid = [self.transform_rectangle(*rect) for rect in target_grid]
        return [t for t in zip(target_grid, source_grid)]
    
# adjust k_1 and k_2 to achieve the required distortion
k_1 = 0.2
k_2 = 0.05
im = Image.open('house.png')
im.putalpha(255)
w, h = im.size
im_deformed = ImageOps.deform(im, BarrelDeformer())
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.imshow(np.hstack((np.array(im), np.array(im_deformed)))), plt.axis('off')
plt.title('The original and the deformed image', size=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]